# How can I delete a file lock that is blocking the deletion of a repo?

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

I'm trying to delete an abandon repo in Azure DevOps 2019. Getting the error:

```
Unable to perform operation on (repo)...
The item (file) ... is locked in workspace ....
```

Note, the file doesn't exist in the repo. It only seems to exist in the workspace.

We have tried using the 'tf.exe workspaces' command but no luck.

I have admin rights. Is there something I can do to cleanup this lock?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below ways to unlock the file:

`tf lock /lock: none` Please see Lock Command for details:
To use the lock command, you must have the Lock permission set to Allow. Having the Unlock other user's changes permission set to Allow is required to remove a lock held by another user if you do not have Write permission for that user's workspace

```
tf lock /lock:none /workspace:workspacename [/recursive][/login:username,[password]] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]
```

`tf undo` The undo command removes any locks on the items. See Undo command

To unlock individual files run the command below in Visual Studio Command Prompt:

```
tf undo "file_path" /workspace:workspace_name
```

e.g.:

```
tf undo $/S/B/ABC/dotNET/Symphony/Tools/xyz/abc/Abc.dll /workspace:Houst01
```

here it will unlock Abc.dll which is inside abc folder.

To unlock the whole folder in one shot:

```
tf undo $/S/B/ABC/dotNET/Symphony/Tools/xyz/abc/* /workspace:Houst01
```

here it will unlock all files which is inside abc folder.